# Local notification in ios app

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, unnotificationrequest

I have requirement to send more than 300 local notification. 
Is there any limit to send local notifications in above iOS 8.0? If you find document regarding this please share.

Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can only schedule 128 notifications at a given time. You can check it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html), under the section Getting the User's attention while in the background.

[image]